# Commit Message and Coverage to shown in Gitlab CI Builds (Gitlab 8.6.5)

Tags: code-coverage, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I recently installed the current version of Gitlab (8.6.5), on one of my machines. 
I have another CI Server running with version 8.0.5.

The older Version shows me the columns 'Message' and 'Coverage' in the builds list, the new version not.

Does anybody know if this is a setting now or did they just remove this?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer versions of GitLab do show the 'Coverage' field in the builds list, but you have to configure the "Test coverage parsing" regex in the project's settings. The test coverage will also show on the individual build pages.

As of GitLab 8.6.5 these are the columns in the build list:
[image: GitLab Build List]

Comment: thx for that. is there a way to see the commit message? the commit hash is actually quite useless to me.

Comment: @Florian Not in the main builds list unfortunately. If you click on the commit hash it takes you a page that will show you the commit message, the changes, and all the builds than ran for that commit.